# How to create multiple profiles using Minio and aws-cli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, minio

I'm trying to connect to several profiles of local Minio instances using `aws-cli` without success. The problem persists when I remove --endpoint_url from the command.
You will find the configuration files below

#### With --endpoint-url:

`aws --profile project01 --endpoint-url http://localhost:9000 s3 ls s3://my-bucket01/`

```
                         PRE data/
2022-10-11 16:21:09      71412 yt.csv
```

`aws --profile project02 --endpoint-url http://localhost:9001 s3 ls s3://my-bucket02/`

```
                         PRE data/
2022-10-11 16:22:09      20989 xt.csv
```

#### Without --endpoint-url

`aws --profile project01 s3 ls s3://my-bucket01/`

`aws --profile project02 s3 ls s3://my-bucket02/`

```
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

#### .aws/credentials

```
[project01]
aws_access_key_id = minioadmin
aws_secret_access_key = minioadmin
[project02]
aws_access_key_id = minioadmin
aws_secret_access_key = minioadmin
```

#### .aws/config

```
[plugins]
endpoint = awscli_plugin_endpoint

[project01]
s3 =
     endpoint_url = http://localhost:9000
[project02]
s3 =
     endpoint_url = http://localhost:9001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in AWS cli. There is a pending issue https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1270 .  You need to specify the endpoint url as part of the command for now